# update query sent from php to SQL Server fails when trigger on target table is enabled

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In php script there is T-SQL update query to SQL Server table. It works fine until I enable trigger on target table. When trigger is enabled I receive DBDatabase error: Invalid SQL, MSSQL Error: 1 (General Error (The MSSQL interface cannot return detailed error messages).)
 Session halted.
But if I run query directly in Management Studio - it works normal even when trigger is On.
How to fix that?

upd:
query `UPDATE T_USER SET US_KEY='30087', US_TEXT=NULL, US_LIC=NULL, US_PRKEY=14696, US_TURAGENT=0, US_REG=1, US_3=0, US_4=0, US_KOL=0, US_2=0, US_ID='test', US_PASSWORD='111', us_manager='manager', US_EMAIL=NULL, US_HOST=NULL, US_ADDRESS=NULL, US_PHONE=NULL, US_COMPANYNAME='Individual', US_AGENT='Individual', US_FAX=NULL WHERE US_KEY = 30087`

trigger

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[tt_updEncryptedPassword] 
   ON  [dbo].[T_USER]
FOR UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF UPDATE(US_PASSWORD)
begin 
declare @str    varchar(256),@uskey int,@encrypted  varchar(256)    
select @uskey=US_KEY,@str=US_PASSWORD from Inserted
DECLARE  @URL SysName,@Header XML,@Body XML
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://tempuri.org/')
SELECT   @URL   = 'http://10.0.10.1/encryptionservice/EncryptionService.asmx'
    ,@Body      = '    <EncryptString xmlns="http://www.qwe.com/">
      <source>'+@str+'</source>
    </EncryptString>'
EXEC    dbo.spSOAPMethodCall @URL,@Header OUT,@Body OUT
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'http://www.qwe.com')
select @encrypted=X.z.value('EncryptStringResult[1]', 'varchar(250)') from @Body.nodes('/EncryptStringResponse') AS X(z)

update [T_USER] set US_BANKNAME=@encrypted where US_KEY=@uskey
end

END
```

Comment: Can you provide more information? Query, tables, columns can be helpful

Comment: Make sure that appropriate permissions are set for the trigger regarding the user that connects through PHP.

Comment: Sure, I checked query also under php user in Studio - it works when trigger enabled.

Comment: Please add the query and trigger code.

Comment: added code in question body.

Comment: BTW, just wondering, do you have premission to run function/Procedure spSOAPMethodCall on that DB you are running your test?

Comment: Just so we're clear, running web service calls in triggers is a real performance killer. You will lock things for far longer than they need to be locked. Secondly, this trigger will only work for updates of 1 row. Multiple row updates will result in the web service call being made for a single, arbitrary row from your updated set.

Comment: Yes, I checked access rights several times and it works under same user which is connecting from php script.

Comment: Matt, this is temporary solution because I need to keep third party code working. The only source I can get encrypted string now is webservice. Just I dont understand why update fails only while running from php script but works if the same user run it on server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved via adding `SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL ON; 
        SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON; 
        SET ANSI_PADDING ON;` before running insert/update.